# Is there any possibility to sort MongoDB results using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an interface with multiple implementations and one of the implementation is using Mongo DB. The method that I am trying to implement has a paramenter a lambda expression which I need to use it to sort the data found in MongoDB. For sorting, MongoDB requires a SortDefinition, but all I have is lambda expression. **Can I convert this lambda expression into a SortDefinition somehow?**

```
public IEnumerable<Car> GetDataSorted(Expression<Func<Car,string>> sortCriteria)
{
    var result = _mongoDBCollection.Find(filterCriteria);
    return result.sort(sortCriteria).ToList();
}
```

For this specific code I am receving an error saying that cannot convert lambda expression to SortDefinition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your `Expression` to get field name and then build your sortDefinition as `BsonDocumentSortDefinition<T>`:

```
var body = sortCriteria.Body.ToString();
var parameter = sortCriteria.Parameters.First() + ".";
var fieldPath = body.Substring(parameter.Length);

SortDefinition<Car> sortDefinition = new BsonDocumentSortDefinition<Car>(
    new BsonDocument(){ { fieldPath, 1 } });

return result.Sort(sortDefinition).ToList();
```

It works for below cases:

```
r.GetDataSorted(c => c.Name); // evaluates to Name
r.GetDataSorted(car => car.Name); // evaluates to Name
r.GetDataSorted(car => car.Nested.Field); // evaluates to Nested.Field
```